# As a newbie to .NET and C#... WPF or WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

What is the best aproach for developing Windows Applications for a newbie in C# ? WinForms or WPF ?

Wich one would be more powerfull ?
Wich one would be easier and faster to develop with ?
Wich one is easier to port to another Os ?

Most of the "practical" C# books focus on WinForms, are there any begginer's C# book using WPF ?

**edit:** Edited the question, now it should be constructive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms+wpf

Comment: Re: WPF books, [a fellow Stack Overflower](http://stackoverflow.com/users/84651/justin-niessner) bought me [Pro WPF in C# 2010 by Apress](http://www.apress.com/9781430272052). It does cover the basics pretty nicely despite being a "Pro" title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please focus on using WPF. You will get introduced to XAML UI programming, which is also the template language for SilverLight and Workflow. You will have a better ROI and it is a more future proof UI technology. The learning curve will be a bit steaper though.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would suggest Silverlight if you're just starting out, not Windows Forms or WPF.  It's a smaller surface than WPF to start with (and easy to transition "up" to WPF if you need it), but it's also closer to the WinRT API, so it would give you a cleaner future path to more deployment targets.

Answer (score 0):

WinForms seems to be "obsolete" so I think it's better to learn WPF.

Comment: this is a bit a strong statement in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is really the one to port to other OS as well, the mono project:

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page claims to have a windows forms 2.0 complete implementation: http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms

if that is more a detail and you don't really care you could try to start with WPF.

my advise would be to focus more on the .NET framework and C# language itself as these are the basis and most of the .NET Framework is available in both so you should know it and get familiar to it, then if your windows derive from a class called Form or another called Window, as long as you know what to put inside and how to approach certain common issues, everything else is a detail (a big detail once you plan to make a huge application of a certain level, bust still a detail).